# Cassandra - crash with "free() invalid pointer"

Tags: cassandra

My Cassandra installation runs on flowing system:

- Linux with Kernel 2.6.32.22
- jna-3.3.0
- Java 1.7.0-b147

Sometimes we are getting following error:

```
*** glibc detected *** /var/opt/java1.7/bin/java: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f66088a6000 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x7f661d7099a8]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x76)[0x7f661d70bab6]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(_dl_deallocate_tls+0x59)[0x7f661e02f349]
/lib/libpthread.so.0[0x7f661de09237]
/lib/libpthread.so.0[0x7f661de0931a]
/lib/libpthread.so.0[0x7f661de0a0bd]
/lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7f661d76564d]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 68:07 537448203                          /var/opt/jdk1.7.0/bin/java
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 68:07 537448203                          /var/opt/jdk1.7.0/bin/java
01bae000-01fd0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
01fd0000-15798000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
40002000-40005000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
40005000-40023000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
40030000-40033000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
40033000-40051000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

Does anyone have similar problems? or maybe some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably best to open a [JIRA ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA) if you can repeat this.  I am aware of posts on the mailing list where it is clear that Cassandra is not fully tested or supported on Java 7.

> Ben Coverston wrote earlier today: " Use a version of the Java 6 runtime, Cassandra hasn't been tested at all with the Java 7 runtime"

[Cassandra mailing list thread addressing this topic](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg21276.html)